# mercurial-server hook

Tags: mercurial

I'm using mercurial-server and hgadmin. All users push repos using hg user. Their keys are stored at /etc/mercurial-server/keys and all of the repos(including hgadmin) are stored at /var/lib/mercurial-server/repos.

The problem: none of the hooks at /var/lib/mercurial-server/repos are working though everyone can push/pull without a problem and no errors are shown with -v.

P.S. `hg showconfig hooks` at `/var/lib/mercurial-server/repos/hgadmin` returns: `/var/lib/mercurial-server/repos/hgadmin/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user hg, group hg`

I know that I need to add an `hgrc` file with

```
[trusted]
user hg
```

but there is no user hg...

EDIT:

```
/var/lib/mercurial-server:                                                                                                           
[root@275238 mercurial-server]# ls -a -l                                                                                                      
total 40
drwx------  4 hg   hg   4096 Sep 26 22:35 .                                                                                                  
drwxr-xr-x 29 root root 4096 Sep 23 18:01 ..                                                                                                            
-rw-------  1 hg   hg     34 Sep 26 21:59 .bash_history                                                                                           
-rw-r--r--  1 hg   hg     18 May 10 21:45 .bash_logout                                                                                              
-rw-r--r--  1 hg   hg    176 May 10 21:45 .bash_profile                                                                                             
-rw-r--r--  1 hg   hg    124 May 10 21:45 .bashrc                                                                                                     
-rw-r--r--  1 hg   hg    610 Sep 23 18:01 .mercurial-server                                                                                  
drwxrwxr-x  5 hg   hg   4096 Sep 23 19:04 repos                                                                                     
drwxr-xr-x  2 hg   hg   4096 Sep 23 18:04 .ssh                                                                                                      
-rw-------  1 hg   hg    577 Sep 23 19:22 .viminfo        

/var/lib/mercurial-server/repos:
[root@275238 repos]# ls -a -l
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 5 hg hg 4096 Sep 23 19:04 .
drwx------ 4 hg hg 4096 Sep 26 22:35 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 hg hg 4096 Sep 23 18:06 anewrepo
drwxr-xr-x 8 hg hg 4096 Sep 27 20:48 gamequark
drwxrwxr-x 3 hg hg 4096 Sep 27 20:48 hgadmin
```

Answer (score 0):

`hg` needs to be the owner and `hg` needs to be the group of `/var/lib/mercurial-server` and everything under it; is that the case right now?

Comment: Yes. Hg is owner of /var/lib/mercurial-server.
I ran chown hg:hg -R /var/lib/mercurial-server.
Same error... :/

Comment: What do the permission bits look like on `/var/lib/mercurial-server`?

Comment: I posted the permissions here: http://chopapp.com/#izbwcpbb
Thank you for your time ;)

Comment: your screenshot suggests that you are running as `root`; how about running `hg showconfig hooks` as the `hg` user?

Comment: There is no hg user... when I do "su hg" I end up in a sh: *****************************************                              
[root@remote ~]# su hg ***************************************** 
sh-4.1$

Comment: that's just plain old shell; you should be able to run your commands there

Comment: well now it looks better: http://chopapp.com/#u7lx0ixp but still when I push changes there it doesn't update :/ any ideas? :)